# How to find largest among 3 numbers only using 2 if else in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

to find the largest number among the input three number using python the given constraint is some blank space, can anyone help me

the program:

```
A,B,C=[int(val) for val in input().split()]
print(______ if _______ else ________ if________ else ________)
```

i am new to python so i thought of using function but there no possibility to add the function so please help me to finish this code.

Comment: Homework question? Can you solve it on paper?

Comment: try solving it with a multi-line traditional `if` then convert to a single line

Comment: can you please explain me more clearly ?

Comment: Take a break. Take a walk. Do something nice. You're probably overthinking it. Come back later and solve it.

Comment: I have been stuck on this question for more then 5 hours just thinking to solve this , i know the solution will be easier but i can't figure out the solution.

Comment: Not sure where you might have been searching, but this link [ternary test](https://www.codespeedy.com/if-elif-else-statement-in-one-single-line-in-python/#:~:text=For%20writing%20if%2Delif%2Delse,else%20statements%20with%20single%20lines.) almost appears to be what the person giving the assignment had in mind.  You might study this link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible solution would be:

```
print(A if (A > B and A > C) else B if (B > A and B > C) else C)
```

However, keep in mind that python has a `max` function so without the constraints this would be much better:

```
print(max(A, B, C))
```

Comment: yeah , due to the constraint i cant able to use max function

Answer (score 1):

Since it is for your homework (as per comment above), I'm not giving you the "copy paste" solution, rather giving you some hint where you can start. Start with a pseudo code  like below first, then try to have it in a single line

```
if A > B
    if C > A 
        # C is the largest
    else
       #
else
    if C > B
        # C is the largest
    else 
        #
```

Comment: yeah its a homework but i really don't know to how to convert the multiline if loop to a single line can you help me with this ?